# Swift 4: SKActionMoveBy goes left instead of right

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

i have an `SKSpriteNode` named `MainTank` however when i try to move the tank, it goes left instead of what i did, here's my code

```
let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: MainTank.position.x + 4, y:0, duration:0.1)
MainTank.run(moveRight)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The moveBy SKAction moves the sprite **by** the specified amount, so adding your sprite's current position does not make sense. Not sure why it is moving left but perhaps your sprite is already at a negative position?

To move by a distance of 4 use:

```
let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x:4, y:0, duration:0.1)
```

Or alternatively use [the moveTo SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417779-moveto).